# Why must I every time initialize tcpClient and networkStream to send data to server?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, network-programming, networkstream

I am new in network programming in c#.
So I decided to write a simple server - client winform application.
I use TcpListener, TcpClient, NetworkStream.
Below is fragment from my code from Client Application.

```
TcpCLient client;
NetworkStream ns;

private void butConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string remoteIp = txtRemoteIp.Text;
    int port = 4848;
    client = new TcpClient(remoteIp, port);
    ns = client.GetStream();           
}

private void butSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string msg = txtMessage.Text;

    //string remoteIp = txtRemoteIp.Text;
    //int port = 4848;
    //client = new TcpClient(remoteIp, port);
    //ns = client.GetStream();

    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
    ns.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    txtMessage.Clear();
}
```

As you see i initiate `client` and `ns` in `butConnect` method. And when I try to send some `msg` in `butSend` method, server side application can not read it.
But, when i remove comments from lines that are in `butsend` method, `msg` sent.
Server side application can get and display the clinet message.
So what is the problem? Why I must initiate `client` and `ns` variables again?

This is server side code.

```
public FormServer() //this is constructor
{
    InitializeComponent();
    initControls();


    ipAddr = IPAddress.Parse(txtIpAddress.Text);
    port = 4848;
    listener = new TcpListener(ipAddr, port);
    listener.Start();

    Thread t = new Thread(Run);
    t.Name = "ListenerThread";
    t.Start(); 
}

private void Run()
{
    while (true)
    {
        while (!listener.Pending())
        {
             Thread.Sleep(200);
        }

    Action<string> action = (string s) => listStatus.Items.Add(s);
    client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

    try
    {
        NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        ns.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
        string msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);

        listStatus.Invoke(action, msg);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
  }                
}
```

Comment: the server could close the connection, it could timeout, maybe you changed `txtRemoteIp.Text`... the problem could be one of many. Can you show the server code? Do you call the `butConnect_Click` method? Could you explain the exact steps you take in order to reproduce it?

Answer (score 0):

The way u create your server, is to wait for a new connect everytime. You can take

```
TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
```

out of your while loop. And it will work as desired. otherwise you will need connect and send your message every time, which is not wrong. And if you take the acceptTcpClient out of your loop, your server will work only for one client.

[Simple Socket Listener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397809(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: I can't understand why it doe not send. When i debug the code, i see that client and ns variables are not null..

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I thought it was a WebForms, Im tryin to simulate the problem here. Try to put a try/catch block in your send method. And tell us if some exceptions occurs

Comment: I did put try catch in butSend method, but it does not give any exception.. :(